# Failed to run vowpal wabbit contextual bandit in daemon mode

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am trying to stream my data to vw in --daemon mode. Right now I'm using just a toy example.
For some reasons I failed to use any of strategies that VW has (epsilon, bag, first). I always get an error. Any quess what is wrong there?

My data:

```
9:0:0.3 | SmartPhone 1 16
7:0:0.3 | SmartPhone 1 21
```

How I launch the training:

```
vw --cb 10 --epsilon 0.1 -d train.vw --save_resume -f model.vw
```

It gives me the error (the same error for --bag 10, --first 2, cb_explore 10--bag 10 btw):

```
PS C:\Users\Default.PC\Desktop\vw> vw -d train.vw --cb 10 --epsilon 0.1 -f model.vw
final_regressor = model.vw
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
Error: unrecognised option '--epsilon'
```

However, if I don't use --epsilon the code works.

```
vw --cb 10 -d train.vw --save_resume -f model.vw
```

And I can use it for prediction:

```
predict: | SmartPhone 1 19 - result is 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which vw version was used, but the command with --epsilon appears to work fine with vw 8.9.2:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop> vw --version
8.9.2 (git commit: 884420267)

PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop> vw -d train.vw --cb 10 --epsilon 0.1 -f model.vw
final_regressor = model.vw
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = train.vw
num sources = 1
Enabled reductions: gd, scorer, csoaa, cb
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
0.000000 0.000000            1            1.0    known        1        4
0.000000 0.000000            2            2.0    known        1        4

finished run
number of examples = 2
weighted example sum = 2.000000
weighted label sum = 0.000000
average loss = 0.000000
total feature number = 8
```

Comment: thank you. I don't know why it was not working for me. But your post gave me a sign that I was on a right way.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `--cb_explore 10` instead of `--cb 10` since it allows the use of exploration algorithms.

More details can be found in the tutorial here:
https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials/contextual_bandits.html

> --cb The contextual bandit module which allows you to optimize predictor based on already collected data, or contextual bandits without exploration.

> --cb_explore The contextual bandit learning algorithm for when the maximum number of actions is known ahead of time and semantics of actions stays the same across examples.